# Rendering quality in JMapFrame

Tags: java, geotools

I would like to improve rendering quality in JMapFrame

```
    this.Map = new MapContent();

    this.MainWindow = new JMapFrame(this.Map);   

    // rendering START
    GTRenderer renderer = this.MainWindow.getMapPane().getRenderer();

    java.util.Map<Object, Object> hints =   renderer.getRendererHints();

    hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
    hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
    hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC); 
    hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);

    renderer.setRendererHints(hints);

    this.MainWindow.getMapPane().setRenderer(renderer);
    // rendering END
```

there is no difference in quality of rendering with or without the code between 
**//rendering START** 
and 
**//rendering END**

Comment: did you check that any of those were different to the defaults? I'm pretty sure we default to quality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are passing Java2D hints to the renderer instead of the Graphic. From the JavaDocs

```
      Rectangle paintArea = new Rectangle(width, height);
      ReferencedEnvelope mapArea = map.getBounds();

      renderer = new StreamingRenderer();
      renderer.setContext(map);

      RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );
      renderer.setJava2DHints(hints);

      Map rendererParams = new HashMap();
      rendererParams.put("optimizedDataLoadingEnabled",new Boolean(true) );

      renderer.setRendererHints( renderParams );

      renderer.paint(graphic, paintArea, mapArea);
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code

```
    GTRenderer     renderer = this.MainWindow.getMapPane().getRenderer();
    RenderingHints hints    = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                                  RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);    

    hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
    hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
    hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
    hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);

    renderer.setJava2DHints(hints);

    this.MainWindow.getMapPane().setRenderer(renderer);
```